# What subtraction operation is being performed here?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with a number of columns, and a `Series`. Both have the same `DateTimeIndex`.

**`DataFrame`:**

```
>>> print(df)

                 AAPL      GOOG       MSFT         AMZN        FB
2018-01-01        NaN       NaN        NaN          NaN       NaN
2018-01-02  -0.667375 -1.567656  -1.161474    -0.674142 -1.886490
2018-01-03   2.004473 -2.802214 -24.084166    -2.447172  2.346972
2018-01-04  -4.261619 -1.471697  -0.027939    -1.753661 -1.835053
2018-01-05  -1.008718 -2.816736  -1.524315    -1.001672  0.080345
2018-01-06 -30.325012 -1.056776  -1.190017  2319.212083 -1.847443
2018-01-07   0.497589  8.588272  -2.434537    -0.793424 -1.194649
2018-01-08  -1.650655 -0.583868 -10.141386     2.704900  7.449458
2018-01-09   1.821119 -6.742207  -0.710584    -0.003800 -1.535461
2018-01-10  -0.624853  0.030330   0.405643    -0.513841 -0.775323
```

**`Series`:**

```
>>> print(ser)

2018-01-01           NaN
2018-01-02     -1.191427
2018-01-03     -4.996421
2018-01-04     -1.869994
2018-01-05     -1.254219
2018-01-06    456.958567
2018-01-07      0.932650
2018-01-08     -0.444310
2018-01-09     -1.434187
2018-01-10     -0.295609
```

If I attempt to subtract the series from the dataframe, I get the following result:

```
>>> df - ser

            2018-01-01 00:00:00  2018-01-02 00:00:00  2018-01-03 00:00:00  \
2018-01-01                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-02                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-03                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-04                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-05                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-06                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-07                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-08                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-09                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-10                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   

            2018-01-04 00:00:00  2018-01-05 00:00:00  2018-01-06 00:00:00  \
2018-01-01                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-02                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-03                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-04                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-05                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-06                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-07                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-08                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-09                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-10                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   

            2018-01-07 00:00:00  2018-01-08 00:00:00  2018-01-09 00:00:00  \
2018-01-01                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-02                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-03                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-04                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-05                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-06                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-07                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-08                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-09                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2018-01-10                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   

            2018-01-10 00:00:00  AAPL  GOOG  MSFT  AMZN  FB  
2018-01-01                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  
2018-01-02                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  
2018-01-03                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  
2018-01-04                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  
2018-01-05                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  
2018-01-06                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  
2018-01-07                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  
2018-01-08                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  
2018-01-09                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  
2018-01-10                  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
```

I also get the following warning:

> ```
> RuntimeWarning: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str', sort order is
> undefined for incomparable objects
>   return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
> ```

I know that I can achieve element-wise subtraction using [`DataFrame.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html)

```
>>> res = df.sub(ser, axis=0)
>>> print(res)

                  AAPL        GOOG        MSFT         AMZN          FB
2018-01-01         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN
2018-01-02    0.524052   -0.376229    0.029954     0.517286   -0.695062
2018-01-03    7.000894    2.194208  -19.087745     2.549249    7.343393
2018-01-04   -2.391625    0.398297    1.842054     0.116333    0.034941
2018-01-05    0.245501   -1.562517   -0.270096     0.252547    1.334565
2018-01-06 -487.283579 -458.015343 -458.148584  1862.253516 -458.806010
2018-01-07   -0.435061    7.655622   -3.367187    -1.726074   -2.127300
2018-01-08   -1.206344   -0.139558   -9.697076     3.149210    7.893768
2018-01-09    3.255306   -5.308020    0.723603     1.430386   -0.101274
2018-01-10   -0.329244    0.325939    0.701251    -0.218232   -0.479714
```

What I don't know, however, is:

- **What operation** is performed using `Dataframe.__sub__`?
- Additionally, it seems very counter-intuitive to me that subtracting a `Series` from a `DataFrame` with matching `Index` types / contents, **doesn't** do an element-wise subtraction. What is the rationale behind not doing this?

Comment: Maybe you can use the [traceback module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) to see what function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the docs you so nicely linked to we find this:

> axis : {0, 1, ‘index’, ‘columns’}
>
> For Series input, axis to match Series index on

And the default value is `'columns'`. This gives us a hint of what happens when you do a substraction, i.e.:

```
df.sub(s) # by not specifying axis you are passing axis=1 / 'columns'
```

**or**

```
df - s
```

None of which will work as you want. Now let us look back on the yellow box. The other alternative is `'index'` and we would match the index (which sounds exactly like what you expect), i.e.:

```
df.sub(s, axis=0) # or 'index' <-- note that you pass a param here
```

**or**

```
(df.T - s).T  #swap columns and rows and swap back again (transpose)
```

---

**Why?** This is a design question. The designers might aswell have set `'index'` as default but for reasons unknown (and probably because it is more frequently used and that the underlying package behind pandas, numpy, does operation that way) they chose `columns`. The numpy behaviour is easily tested by doing this: `df.values - s.values` which indeed operates on columns where as you are interested in rows (index).

**Short why:** numpy works like this.

---

The most elegant solution for this is to use `.sub()` and specifying `axis='index'`. (or 0, but index might be more readable in this case)